# Show alert on Gravity Forms datepicker for Saturdays

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm using this modified script to disable Mondays and Sundays in the Gravity Forms datepicker which works fine.

But the part that does not work is the alert for when Saturday is clicked. Here's my code:

```
// Disable Sunday and Monday in datepicker
function hideDays(date) {
    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Sunday";
    weekday[1]="Monday";
    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
    weekday[4]="Thursday";
    weekday[5]="Friday";
    weekday[6]="Saturday";
    //console.log(weekday[date.getDay()]);
    if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Monday' || weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Sunday') {
        return [false, '', 'Not available'];
    } else if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Monday' || weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Sunday') {
        return [false, '', 'Not available'];
    } 

    // Show alwert when Saturday is clicked
    if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Saturday') {
        alert('hello!');
    } else if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Saturday') {
        alert('hello!');
    }
    return [true];
}
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', hideDays);
});
```

Instead, the alert is showing immediately without having to click.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `beforeShowDay` is called before any date is _displayed_ on the calendar. It has nothing whatsoever to do with actual clicks on a date item later on.